# Does PriorityQueue maintain natural order?

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue, comparable

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their
>   natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction
>   time, depending on which constructor is used.

However, in the following example, when I print the whole queue at once, the queue's elements are printed in random order. On the other hand, if I poll the elements one by one they are printed in natural order.

**Could someone explain me this ambiguious behavior? Or Am I missing something?**

```
public class QueueExample {


    public static class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Employee(int id, String name){
            this.id=id;
            this.name=name;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return "id:"+id+" name:"+name;
        }

        public int compareTo(Employee emp){
            return name.compareTo(emp.name);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Queue<Employee> priority=new PriorityQueue<Employee>();

        priority.add(new Employee(101, "Atlas"));
        priority.add(new Employee(102, "Ztlas"));
        priority.add(new Employee(101, "Ftlas"));
        priority.add(new Employee(101, "Ptlas"));

        System.out.println(priority);

        System.out.println(priority.poll());
        System.out.println(priority.poll());
        System.out.println(priority.poll());
        System.out.println(priority.poll());

    }

}
```

**Output:**

> [id:101 name:Atlas, id:101 name:Ptlas, id:101 name:Ftlas, id:102
>   name:Ztlas]
>
> id:101 name:Atlas
>
> id:101 name:Ftlas
>
> id:101 name:Ptlas
>
> id:102 name:Ztlas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit further down in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#method.summary) it says:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

Since `AbstractCollection`'s `toString` (which `PriorityQueue` inherits) returns a string in the iteration order, you get no particular order from it.